# validation of variables with isset

Tags: php, isset

So I'm reading this book and learning PHP. In one of the exercises I had to write a form containing a couple of hidden values, then write a "handler" that checks whether these values have been initialized.

The code looks like this:

```
    $time = (!isset($_POST["time"])) ? NULL : $_POST["time"];
    $user = (!isset($_POST["user"])) ? NULL : $_POST["user"];
```

My question is, is there any reason why the author suggests `!isset`, as opposed to straightup `isset`? Why not do it like below?

```
    $time = (isset($_POST["time"])) ? $_POST["time"] : NULL;
    $user = (isset($_POST["user"])) ? $_POST["user"] : NULL;
```

Thanks! Any pros / cons of either method?

Comment: It's probably a personal preference of the book's author. There is no technical reason to write it one way or the other. The second version is more readable. Remove the parentheses around `isset()`, they are not needed.

Comment: Agree with @axiac. I prefer 'check-if-true' in ternaries as you propose but is very common and standard 'checking-if-false' in other situation to do some validations. For example: if not auth then throw exception...

Comment: Thanks guys -- for the confirmation and for the tip @axiac